# Is it possible to sort the columns of each row?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table:

```
create table SomeTable( 
    N1 int(11) not null default 0,
    N2 int(11) not null default 0,
    N3 int(11) not null default 0,
    N4 int(11) not null default 0,
    N5 int(11) not null default 0
)
```

The table has only one row, like this:

```
N1 : 1
N2 : 2
N3 : 5
N4 : 0
N5 : 3
```

When I query `select * from table`, I get:

```
N1, N2, N3, N4, N5
 1,  2,  5,  0,  3
```

Is it possible to sort data like this?

```
N3, N5, N2, N1, N4
 5,  3,  2,  1,  0
```

Comment: `select * from table order by second_col desc`

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of atrocious design

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do it  You can order rows but cannot order columns... you can specify order of selected columns like this:

```
select N3, N5, N2, N1, N4 from SomeTable
```

Comment: Yes))) I know that it's possible in hacky way but for real project, it's definitely the wrong way... And big, sophisticated query - it's only the sign that something going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically affect column *names*, but you can order the values:

```
select
    greatest(N1, N2, N3, N4, N5) as col1,
    case greatest(N1, N2, N3, N4, N5)
        when N1 then greatest(N2, N3, N4, N5) 
        when N2 then greatest(N1, N3, N4, N5) 
        when N3 then greatest(N1, N2, N4, N5) 
        when N4 then greatest(N1, N2, N3, N5) 
        when N5 then greatest(N1, N2, N3, N4)
    end as col2,
    case greatest(N1 + N2, N1 + N3, N1 + N4, N1 + N5, N2 + N3, N2 + N4, N2 + N5, N3 + N4, N3 + N5, N4 + N5)
        when N1 + N2 then greatest(N3, N4, N5) 
        when N1 + N3 then greatest(N2, N4, N5)
        when N1 + N4 then greatest(N2, N3, N5)
        when N1 + N5 then greatest(N2, N3, N4)
        when N2 + N3 then greatest(N1, N4, N5)
        when N2 + N4 then greatest(N1, N3, N5)
        when N2 + N5 then greatest(N1, N3, N4)
        when N3 + N4 then greatest(N1, N2, N5)
        when N3 + N5 then greatest(N1, N2, N4)
        when N4 + N5 then greatest(N1, N2, N3)
    end as col3,
    case least(N1, N2, N3, N4, N5)
        when N1 then least(N2, N3, N4, N5) 
        when N2 then least(N1, N3, N4, N5) 
        when N3 then least(N1, N2, N4, N5) 
        when N4 then least(N1, N2, N3, N5) 
        when N5 then least(N1, N2, N3, N4)
    end as col4,
    least(N1, N2, N3, N4, N5) as col5
from table
```

This will work with any number of rows in the table (not just 1 as in your case).

Comment: Will you use this query in real project?)

Comment: Moreover, your query is wrong( You have to select 1 record and appropriate columns names accordingly to values, like `N3, N5, N2, N1, N4` not `col1, col2, col3, col4, col5` like in your query.

Comment: Or you could just fix your broken table design

Comment: @Strawberry I think it's a broken query requirement too. I've never heard of a application requiring ordered columns. I felt unclean coding this, but I did it mainly to disprove vlad's contention that it was impossible... I enjoy doing "impossible" things with code.

Comment: @Bohemian Well, how about a sproc for tonight's lottery numbers? ;-)